# Python and snowflake the schemachange is not working and returning an invalid syntax error

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-migration

I am trying to run `schemachange` from jupyter notebook. I have the `SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD` set in the `environment table`.

The command I am using is:

```
schemachange [-h] [-f 'C:\mypath\migration'] -a 'myaccount.snowflakecomputing.com' -u 'snowflake_test' -r 'analyst' -w 'DEVWH' [-d 'TEST_DB'] [-c CHANGE_HISTORY_TABLE] [-ac] [-v];
```

But it keeps returning an `invalid syntax` error. The schema `schemachange` is available withint the `TEST_DB` as well.

If I ran `pip show schemachange` command:

> Name: schemachange Version: 2.9.1 Summary: A Database Change

> Management tool for Snowflake Home-page:

> https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/schemachange Author:

> jamesweakley/jeremiahhansen Author-email: None License: UNKNOWN

> Location: c:\users\myuser\anaconda3\lib\site-packages Requires:

> snowflake-connector-python Required-by:  Note: you may need to restart

> the kernel to use updated packages.

Comment: Are you actually typing those square brackets? Like `]` and `[`. Those usually mean "optional", not to be typed

Comment: I removed them. Now the migration is not running but no errors but a warning about pytorch version.